# minterpolate:slowmotion video with stuttering / stroboskop effect

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video

i have the follow issue: i would stretch a video from 11min to 22min.
The Input video have a frame rate of 30FPS

i stretch ( slowmo) ist with:
ffmpeg -i 1min.mkv -r 60 -filter:v setpts=2.0*PTS output.mkv
(tested with 120 or 240FPS too)

after that the Video stutter and i need to smooth it.

I use the following command:

ffmpeg -i output.mkv -filter minterpolate=mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:vsbmc=1:fps=30 output_minterpolate.mkv

The Result is great but there are some stuttering parts, or i say some parts with stroboscok effect.
I have uplaod a testfile and you can see the effect at second 9 at the tree on the right side and at second 18: the sign on the left side.

in the complete Video i see sometimes this "strobo"-Effect on different things.

Is there a way to improve this / eliminate this effect ?

Here is the Test-Video:
https://youtu.be/kxaIQS0YTQA

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, and solved it by changing the interpolation algorithm from mci to blend.

1. Double the frame rate of the source video (mine was 50fps)

ffmpeg -i video_50fps.mp4 -filter "minterpolate='mi_mode=blend:**fps=100**'" video_100fps.mp4

2. Change the PTS to double the video length, and set the frame rate back to 50 fps

ffmpeg -i video_100fps.mp4 **-r 50** -filter:v "setpts=**2.0***PTS" video_slow.mp4

Comment: nowadays the first line should be -filter:v not -filter, or it will give an error on audio stream.

Comment: can this be chained into one single ffmpeg command?